# Pra que serve a opção "array" no app/config/session.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Sei que no Laravel 4 podemos configurar vários meios de salvar os dados da sessão. São os mecanismos de armazenamos opcionais de sessão.

Dentre eles, podemos selecionar `memcached`, `database`, `cookie`, `apc` e `file`, que por sinal são muito comuns.

Porém existe lá também uma opção chamada `array`.

Se selecionar essa opção `array`, o que o Laravel 4 fará internamente para salvar os dados da sessão?

Quer dizer, entendo perfeitamente o tipo de operação que será realizada nas outras opções, mas essa não deu pra entender.

Comment: Vai me dar -1 de novo, amigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme trecho da [documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session):

> array - sessions will be stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests.

Esse driver irá armazenar a session em um array simples, e não será persistido entre as requisições. Ou seja, a session não será salva e será perdida na próxima requisição.

**Mas para que eu usaria isso?**

Isso é uma pratica para ser utilizada em testes automatizados, assim serviços externos não precisam ser requisitados ou acessar o disco ao testar um trecho que utilizar session, aumentando a velocidade dos testes.

Outros drivers comuns para outras configurações ao executar testes são:

- queue: null
- cache: array
- database: sqlite

Answer (score 3):

"array - sessions will be stored in a simple PHP array and will not be persisted across requests." - Retirado do site da documentação do Laravel (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session)

Em uma tradução livre: "Array - sessões serão armazenadas em uma matriz simples PHP e não serão persistentes entre solicitações."